# VBoxManage (LockMachine): Docker machine created by chef

Tags: docker, chef-infra, virtualbox

I want to create default machine for Docker with Chef.

I am using command:

```
docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox --virtualbox-host-dns-resolver=true default
```

My problem is that when I run it inside Chef (with `execute` resource, but I've also tried `batch` and `powershell_script`) it runs perfectly fine (machine is added inside Docker), but it does not work inside VBox (machine isn't even created).

```
docker-machine ls -t 20
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown

docker-machine start
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 8240EM --nicpromisc2 deny --hostonlyadapter2 VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter --cableconnected2 on failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 507 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Now I can't remove this machine, because there are three `VBoxHeadless.exe` and `VBoxNetDHCP.exe` processes.

What is odd, the same command run inside `cmd` by me works and machine is in started state:

```
docker-machine ls -t 20
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.05.0-ce
```

What's the difference...? Why does it not work under Chef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found out, what was the problem.

I was running Chef as administrator and had other console with normal user priviledges.

Main problem is, when running `docker-machine` with admin priviledges, something goes wrong and it isn't created for user but for admin (problem exists even on Linux system - I've checked it).

To resolve this problem, one should run this `execute` resource without admin priviledges - and I don't really know, how to do it in Chef, but this is a whole new question to ask.

Comment: See [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html) documentation ?

Comment: I've found there that `user` and `password` exist - but I don't want to force users to provide their passwords... In fact, many users don't have password set at all. I just want `execute` make non-UAC process.

Comment: execute inherit chef context... I don't get what's your overall goal

Comment: As said in answer - the problem is that configuring `docker machine` as admin in Windows is buggy and can't be used after by normal user. In fact, you have to run this command without admin priviledges - hence Chef should run it without them.

Comment: I'd dig on vbox permission personnaly